# Angular: Add value to input from onClick event button

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make an Edit Modal using Angular. the td fields get a value from this table and send it to a modal using the (click) event

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let mascota of mascotas" class="text-center ">
    <td>{{mascota.name}}</td>
    <td>{{mascota.birthDate}}</td>
    <td>{{mascota.species.name}}</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-info mx-2">Detalles</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning mx-2" (click)="openSM(contenido,mascota)">Editar</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger mx-2">Remover</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the function that I made in the component, used a const in order to get the values and send it to the modal

```
openSM(contenido, mascota) {
    const modalRef = this.modal.open(contenido,{size:'lg',centered:true});
    modalRef["mascota"] = mascota;
    console.log(modalRef);
}
```

And this is the modal where I'm tying to get the value

```
<ng-template #contenido let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Editar datos de mascota</h4>
    <button class="close" aria-label="close" type="button" (click)="modal.close()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="editform" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="form-group m-t-10">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <label>Nombre de Mascota:</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" value="mascota.name" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

But when I click on the Edit button it didn't recognize the value
And when I used {{}} the const get an 'undefined' value

[Error from Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6znUz.png)

[Contenido Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiwsC.png)
Is there any way to get that value and put it into the input tag? I want to do the same with the others td fields, but first this needs to work well

[Console log of the inputs in the constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M21cz.png)

Comment: Can you share the `contenido` data? Also just a wild guess `value="{{mascota?.name}}"`

Comment: I upload the contenido data that I store in the const modalRef (2nd image); also I tried with {{mascota?.name}} and the undefined error disappear, but the value stills blank

Comment: log the inputs in the modal constructor and check what you receive

Comment: Done, you can see on the 3rd picture, with the 'mascota' parameter I get the data that I want,  is there any way to call it from the modal?

Comment: You're assigning `mascota` to `modal` after opening it. I would suggest you pass on the data `this.modal.open({contenido, mascota},{size:'lg',centered:true});` like this then try to access it accordingly.

Comment: When I add mascota to that line I get "ASSERTION ERROR: Type passed in is not ComponentType, it does not have 'ɵcmp' property" in the HTML and the modal doesn't open